# Kafka producer send message expiring duo to 30003 ms has passed since last append

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

I'm using Kafka 0.10.1.1 and write a test producer, but I get an error in `producer.send` `onCompletion` callback:

```
        producer.send(record, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
            if (e != null){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Producer with Config: `timeout.ms=30000, linger.ms=5, batch.size=1000`

Got the following error message:

> Expiring 1 record(s) for testtopic-2 due to 30004 ms has passed since
>   last append

But this error message just appeared sometimes. The producer can work well sometimes.

Comment: Just increase the timeout value... from 30000 to 60000 (for example)

Comment: I have try set timout.ms=60000, it still have such error message, even set timeouts=180000, error message is still there.

Comment: Try a larger batch.size.

Comment: actually, i just send 1 message for testing, the expiring error appears. Is there anything related with the batch.size? And it seems the error message will be appeared for every message now....

Comment: It sounds a lot like you are having connectivity issues to your broker. The error message you see occurs when the batch is "full" (i.e. linger.ms or batch size is reached) and the producer couldn't update the metadata it needs to send the request within the timeout that you see in the error message.

Comment: yes, it's caused by the automatically created topic, if i create the topic from  shell, it works well.

Comment: It is not recommended to enable auto topic creation. It's always better to do it manually, because it takes some time that brokers exchange meta data (this exchanges happens async)

Comment: I am also receiving this error and have asked a question here, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932127/kafka-failed-to-update-metadata`. Could you all please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Say a topic has 100 partitions (0-99). Kafka lets you produce records to a topic by specifying a particular partition. Faced the issue where I'm trying to produce to partition > 99, because brokers reject these records.

Its highly probable that your topic (testtopic) has less than 3 partition where as you are trying to produce to testtopic-2.

Answer (score -4):

When you create the consumer, set `ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG` to `true`. 
 That will solve a problem.

Comment: The question refers to a producer, not a consumer.